# How to change icon colors in the Project Explorer of Spyder based on the extension

Tags: icons, spyder, project-management

I Have my project explored opened, and I notice that .py files and .txt/.csv ones share the same icon with the same color (see the image below). I would like to change the layout of it so that I can immediately see if the file that I am looking at is a program or a text file (for example, if the file ends in .py I would like to see it highlighted in red, if it's a .txt in white and so on), like the pycharm project explorer. Is there a way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to change icons or their colors at the moment.

However, we could improve the situation by assigning different icons to Python and CSV files. If you're interested in this possibility, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues).